# Use sed to delete a matched regexp and the line (or two) underneath it

Tags: sed, line

OK I found this question:

[How do I delete a matching line, the line above and the one below it, using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876446/how-do-i-delete-a-matching-line-the-line-above-and-the-one-below-it-using-sed)

and just spent the last hour trying to write something that will match a string and delete the line containing the string and the line beneath it (or a variant - delete 2 lines beneath it).

I feel I'm now typing random strings. Please somebody help me.

Comment: Does it have to be a single sed command?

Comment: I've managed to do it in 2 sed commands now:

sed '/XYZ/{n
/STATE/d}'|sed '/XYZ/d'

which works :) but now I'm curious if it can be done in one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood that correctly, to delete match line and one line after

```
/matchstr/{N;d;}
```

Match line and two lines after

```
/matchstr/{N;N;d;}
```

- `N` brings in the next line
- `d` - deletes the resulting single line

Comment: Your command will work without replacing the newlines, just do `/matchstr/{N;d}` or `/matchstr/{N;N;d}`

Answer (score 0):

you can use awk. eg search for the word "two" and skip 2 lines after it

```
$ cat file
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
$ awk -vnum=2 '/two/{for(i=0;i<=num;i++)getline}1' file
one
five
six
seven
eight
```