# Delete line using sed with dot in string

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I tried using this answers [stack overflow #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061131/use-sed-to-delete-a-matched-regexp-and-the-line-or-two-underneath-it) and this site [regexp](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html), but I can't delete line with dot inside, using `\` before `.` doesn't help. The line I'm trying to delete is:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

I'm try delete this line by writing

```
sed -i /'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"'/{d} .testing
```

Effect? `sed: -e expression #1, char 21: unknown command: '.'`
When trying another way, escaping dot

```
sed -i /'export PATH="$HOME/\.rbenv/bin:$PATH"'/{d} .testing
```

Effect? `sed: -e expression #1, char 21: unknown command: '\'`
I have no clue how to work this around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed '\~export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH~d' .testing
```

**Reference:** [How to use different delimiters for regex search in sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses)

Thanks to @jaypal for the link.

**Edit:** If you use in a script, try adding -i to sed command like this for inline editing:

```
sed -i.bak '\~export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH~d' .testing
```

Use -i.bak for backup of original file.

Comment: +1: @SzymonBłaszczyński You can read more about this [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses) on how to use different delimiters for regex search.

Comment: @jaypal: Thanks for sharing that useful link. Let me put it up with my answer.

Comment: @SzymonBłaszczyński: Did you have any problem with this answer that you removed the accept mark?

Comment: WOW! Almost deleted my whole `bashrc`! It does delete the whole file, not just one line! or maybe it's me. I typed `sed '\~lol~d' ~/.testing > ~/.testing` and it zeroed the whole file, do you know how to do this another way, to preserve the rest of text?

Comment: That is not because of `sed` command I suggested. It is because of your use of `~/.testing > ~/.testing`. You cannot edit and redirect into same file. Use it like this: **`sed -i.bak '\~export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH~d' .testing`**

Comment: ok, I'm new to shell scripting. thank you for help, and yep, your answer is still accepted, thought for a while that the different sed argument actually deleted whole file. my bad.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong about redirecting the file. If you want to add new portion to existing file you would use `>>` command to append changes to the end of the file.