# How do I delete a matching line and the previous one?

Tags: unix, sed, grep, pattern-matching

I need delete a matching line and one previous to it. 
e.g In file below I need to remove lines 1 & 2.

I tried "grep -v -B 1 "page.*of.*" 1.txt 
and I expected it to not print the matchning lines and the context.

I tried the [How do I delete a matching line, the line above and the one below it, using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876446/how-do-i-delete-a-matching-line-the-line-above-and-the-one-below-it-using-sed) but could not understand the sed usage.

```
---1.txt--
**document 1**                         -> 1
**page 1 of 2**                        -> 2

testoing
testing

super crap blah

**document 1**
**page 2 of 2**
```

Comment: try [`tac file | sed -e '/foo/,+1d' | tac`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31227307/2297751)

Answer (score 14):

You want to do something very similar to the [answer given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876446/how-do-i-delete-a-matching-line-the-line-above-and-the-one-below-it-using-sed/889134#889134)

```
sed -n '
/page . of ./ { #when pattern matches
n #read the next line into the pattern space
x #exchange the pattern and hold space
d #skip the current contents of the pattern space (previous line)
}

x  #for each line, exchange the pattern and hold space
1d #skip the first line
p  #and print the contents of pattern space (previous line)

$ { #on the last line
x #exchange pattern and hold, pattern now contains last line read
p #and print that
}'
```

And as a single line

```
sed -n '/page . of ./{n;x;d;};x;1d;p;${x;p;}' 1.txt
```

Comment: Note that you can do it on one line: `sed -n '/page 1/{n;x;d;};x;1d;$G;p' 1.txt`

Comment: @Beta: Of course, the extra lines, etc. are merely annotation

Comment: Why was this downvoted? it does what the question asker wanted (and is in sed to boot)

Comment: Be careful! When the match line next to each other, it will retain the last match line.
For example, the file like this
`1higk
2rst
3rst
4igk
5opq`
and if the match line is 'rst'
`sed -n '/rst/{n;x;d;};x;1d;p;${x;p;}' file`,
the result it return:
`3rst
4igk
5opq`
This time, the 3rd line ‘3rst'  is not removed.

Answer (score 4):

`grep -v -B1` doesnt work because it will skip those lines but will include them later on (due to the `-B1`.  To check this out, try the command on:

```
**document 1**                         -> 1
**page 1 of 2**                        -> 2

**document 1**
**page 2 of 2**
**page 3 of 2**
```

You will notice that the `page 2` line will be skipped because that line won't be matched and the next like wont be matched.

There's a simple awk solution:

```
awk '!/page.*of.*/ { if (m) print buf; buf=$0; m=1} /page.*of.*/ {m=0}' 1.txt
```

The awk command says the following:

If the current line has that "page ... of ", then it will signal that you haven't found a valid line.  If you do not find that string, then you print the previous line (stored in buf) and reset the buffer to the current line (hence forcing it to lag by 1)

Comment: Probably need to append `END { if (m) print buf }` not to skip the last line.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -vf <(grep -B1 "page.*of" file | sed '/^--$/d') file
```

Comment: You want to add an `-x` option to the outer `grep`. This isn't terribly efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Not too familiar with sed, but here's a perl expression to do the trick:

```
cat FILE | perl -e '@a = <STDIN>;
                    for( $i=0 ; $i <= $#a ; $i++ ) { 
                     if($i > 0 && $a[$i] =~ /xxxx/) { 
                       $a[$i] = ""; 
                       $a[$i-1] = "";
                     }
                    } print @a;'
```

edit:

where "xxxx" is what you are trying to match.

Comment: And the Useless Use of Cat should go.

Comment: Yes, certain pieces of this solution can be criticized, but the general concept is solid and the example code implements it fairly well. It is easy to understand. Enough to get someone started. And that is the whole point of an answer here. It doesn't need to be perfect.
I like this answer. It certainly helped me with a problem similar to the original question.

Comment: If you want to delete lines containing `xxxx` but nothing more, I would suggest `xxxx\r` and `xxxx\r\n` in case other lines are `xxxxabc`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I was trying to use the awk command given by [Foo Bah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7378912/1957820)
to delete the matching line and the previous one. I have to use it multiple times, so for the matching part I use a variable. The given awk command works, but when using a variable it does not work (i.e. it does not delete the matching & prev. line). I tried:

`awk -vvar="page.*of.*" '!/$var/ { if (m) print buf; buf=$0; m=1} /$var/ {m=0}' 1.txt`