# How can i replace text with sed by matching previous line

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I have this file:

```
user_default:
    resource: "@UserDefaultBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
Other_default:
    resource: "@PeopDefaultBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

I want to replace the prefix under `user_default` to `/user`

I know how I can replace in single line, but I don't know how to check the previous lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^\S/{h;b};G;/^user_default:/M{s/(prefix:\s*\S).*/\1user/};P;d' /file
```

This copies a section header into the hold space and thereafter appends it to lines within that section. If the line contains both `user_default:` and `prefix:` it does the required substitution.

N.B. It uses the multi-line switch `M` to check that the section header begins with the required label.

EDIT:
Missed the obvious!:

```
sed -r '/^user_default:/,/^\s*prefix:/{s/\(prefix:\s*).*/\1\/user/}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's not that easy with sed, but it's doable ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7378865/11621) and modify to suit to your needs if sed is the only option). I'd recommend to use awk for this job, like:

```
awk '/^user_default:/ { print ; ud=1 ; next}
     /^ +resource:/ && ud==1 {print gensub("@UserDefaultBundle","/user",1) ; ud=0 ; next }
     { print }' INPUTFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

This AWK solution should work, change the variables accordingly.

```
awk -v p="prefix:" -v x="user_default:" '{
{!/^[[:space:]]/ && NF=1 && a=$NF}
{if ((a==x) && ($0~p))
sub(/\//,"/user")}
}1' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
sed -r '/user_default:/{:a;N;/prefix/!{/\n\S/!ba};s!(prefix:\s*).*!\1/user!}' file
```

This command will avoid to apply the change to wrong session, if "prefix" is not exist in user_default session.