# How to delete lines from file with structure criteria

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with a sudden structure, and when the structure is not met I would like to delete those lines. So the structure should be: 1) a line starting with the word "Sequence", 2) a line starting with the word "Start", 3) a line starting with a number.

Now in my file some line do not have the number, but do have the first two lines (the number line was removed with grep). I hope to find a way with awk or sed, to remove the two preceding lines when there is no number line. Hope this is possible?

```
cat file.txt
Sequence: HM855457_IGHV1-8*02_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_24..319_296nt_1_____296+0=296__rev-compl_     from: 1   to: 296
Start     End  Strand Pattern                 Mismatch Sequence
217     225       + pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN        . aacacctcc
Sequence: MG719312_IGHV1-8*03_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_127..422_296nt_1_____296+0=296___     from: 1   to: 296
Start     End  Strand Pattern                 Mismatch Sequence
217     225       + pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN        . aacacctcc
Sequence: M99648_IGHV2-26*01_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_164..464_301nt_1_____301+0=301___     from: 1   to: 301
Start     End  Strand Pattern                 Mismatch Sequence
Sequence: L21969_IGHV2-70*01_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_144..444_301nt_1_____301+0=301___     from: 1   to: 301
Start     End  Strand Pattern                 Mismatch Sequence
176     184       + pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN        . aatactaca
Sequence: X92241_IGHV2-70*02_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_144..433_290nt_1_____290+0=290_partialin3'__     from: 1   to: 290
Start     End  Strand Pattern                 Mismatch Sequence
176     184       + pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN        . aatactaca
```

Expected output:

```
cat file.txt
Sequence: HM855457_IGHV1-8*02_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_24..319_296nt_1_____296+0=296__rev-compl_     from: 1   to: 296
Start     End  Strand Pattern                 Mismatch Sequence
217     225       + pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN        . aacacctcc
Sequence: MG719312_IGHV1-8*03_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_127..422_296nt_1_____296+0=296___     from: 1   to: 296
Start     End  Strand Pattern                 Mismatch Sequence
217     225       + pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN        . aacacctcc
Sequence: L21969_IGHV2-70*01_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_144..444_301nt_1_____301+0=301___     from: 1   to: 301
Start     End  Strand Pattern                 Mismatch Sequence
176     184       + pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN        . aatactaca
Sequence: X92241_IGHV2-70*02_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_144..433_290nt_1_____290+0=290_partialin3'__     from: 1   to: 290
Start     End  Strand Pattern                 Mismatch Sequence
176     184       + pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN        . aatactaca
```

Comment: Can you show expected output and your attempt at it?

Comment: Sigh. This would be utterly trivial to tweak the awk script in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51745195/1745001) to do. This is what I was trying to warn you about wrt using sed for tasks like this - now with the tiniest requirements change from your previous question you need a completely different solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk` command:

```
awk '/^[0-9]+/ && NR==a["Sequence:"]+2 && NR==a["Start"]+1 {
   print r["Sequence:"] ORS r["Start"] ORS $0
}
/^(Sequence:|Start)/ {
   a[$1]=NR
   r[$1]=$0
}' file
```

```
Sequence: HM855457_IGHV1-8*02_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_24..319_296nt_1_____296+0=296__rev-compl_     from: 1   to: 296
Start     End  Strand Pattern                 Mismatch Sequence
217     225       + pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN        . aacacctcc
Sequence: MG719312_IGHV1-8*03_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_127..422_296nt_1_____296+0=296___     from: 1   to: 296
Start     End  Strand Pattern                 Mismatch Sequence
217     225       + pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN        . aacacctcc
Sequence: L21969_IGHV2-70*01_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_144..444_301nt_1_____301+0=301___     from: 1   to: 301
Start     End  Strand Pattern                 Mismatch Sequence
176     184       + pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN        . aatactaca
Sequence: X92241_IGHV2-70*02_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_144..433_290nt_1_____290+0=290_partialin3'__     from: 1   to: 290
Start     End  Strand Pattern                 Mismatch Sequence
176     184       + pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN        . aatactaca
```

Comment: This is working very well, thanks. What manual/reference do you use for awk? I would like to use awk more, but hard to find good reference.

Comment: Start with http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html and https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf then you can check some `awk` answers on SO itself.

Comment: @b.nota you'll find manual and learning resources in tag wikis... https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info

Answer (score 1):

```
% awk '
  $1 == "Sequence:" {seq   = $0}
  $1 == "Start"     {start = $0}
  $1 ~ /^[0-9]*$/ && l "Start" && L == "Sequence:" {print seq;print start;print}
  {L = l;}
  {l = $1}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

for files that can fit within memory, you can slurp entire file and process

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/^Sequence.*\nStart.*\n(?!\d)//m' ip.txt
```

- `-0777` slurp entire file
- `m` flag, so that `^` and `$` anchors will work in multi-line string as well
- `^Sequence.*\nStart.*\n(?!\d)` match `^Sequence.*\nStart.*\n` only if it is not followed by a digit. Note that `.` will not match newline character unless `s` flag is used

Alternatively, you could match and print only the correct grouping

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print /^Sequence.*\nStart.*\n\d.*\n/mg' ip.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

To ONLY print the 3-line records all you need is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^Sequence:/ { lineNr=0; rec="" }
{ rec = (++lineNr > 1 ? rec ORS : "") $0 }
lineNr == 3 { print rec }
```

For example:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Sequence: HM855457_IGHV1-8*02_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_24..319_296nt_1_____296+0=296__rev-compl_     from: 1   to: 296
Start     End  Strand Pattern                 Mismatch Sequence
217     225       + pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN        . aacacctcc
Sequence: MG719312_IGHV1-8*03_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_127..422_296nt_1_____296+0=296___     from: 1   to: 296
Start     End  Strand Pattern                 Mismatch Sequence
217     225       + pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN        . aacacctcc
Sequence: L21969_IGHV2-70*01_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_144..444_301nt_1_____301+0=301___     from: 1   to: 301
Start     End  Strand Pattern                 Mismatch Sequence
176     184       + pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN        . aatactaca
Sequence: X92241_IGHV2-70*02_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_144..433_290nt_1_____290+0=290_partialin3'__     from: 1   to: 290
Start     End  Strand Pattern                 Mismatch Sequence
176     184       + pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN        . aatactaca
```

but for a far more useful approach to analyzing your data, look again at the script at the bottom of [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51745195/1745001). To tweak that to discard records than have less than 3 lines all you need to do is move the `lineNr=0` setting from inside the `lineNr==3` block to a new `/Sequence:/` block and the script will continue to work to give an array that you can access fields by their names:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^Sequence:/ { lineNr = 0 }

++lineNr == 1 {
    delete fldNr2tag
    delete tagNr2tag
    delete tag2val
    numTags = 0

    for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) {
        sub(/:.*/,"",$i)
        tag = $i (i>1 ? "" : 1) # to distinguish the 2 "Sequence" tags
        val = $(i+1)
        tagNr2tag[++numTags] = tag
        tag2val[tag] = val
    }
}
lineNr == 2 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        tag = $i
        fldNr2tag[i] = tag
    }
}
lineNr == 3 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        tag = fldNr2tag[i]
        val = $i
        tagNr2tag[++numTags] = tag
        tag2val[tag] = val
    }

    prt()
}

function prt(   tagNr, tag, val) {
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tagNr2tag[tagNr]
        val = tag2val[tag]
        printf "tag2val[%s] = <%s>\n", tag, val
    }
    print "----"
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
tag2val[Sequence1] = <HM855457_IGHV1-8*02_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_24..319_296nt_1_____296+0=296__rev-compl_>
tag2val[from] = <1>
tag2val[to] = <296>
tag2val[Start] = <217>
tag2val[End] = <225>
tag2val[Strand] = <+>
tag2val[Pattern] = <pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN>
tag2val[Mismatch] = <.>
tag2val[Sequence] = <aacacctcc>
----
tag2val[Sequence1] = <MG719312_IGHV1-8*03_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_127..422_296nt_1_____296+0=296___>
tag2val[from] = <1>
tag2val[to] = <296>
tag2val[Start] = <217>
tag2val[End] = <225>
tag2val[Strand] = <+>
tag2val[Pattern] = <pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN>
tag2val[Mismatch] = <.>
tag2val[Sequence] = <aacacctcc>
----
tag2val[Sequence1] = <L21969_IGHV2-70*01_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_144..444_301nt_1_____301+0=301___>
tag2val[from] = <1>
tag2val[to] = <301>
tag2val[Start] = <176>
tag2val[End] = <184>
tag2val[Strand] = <+>
tag2val[Pattern] = <pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN>
tag2val[Mismatch] = <.>
tag2val[Sequence] = <aatactaca>
----
tag2val[Sequence1] = <X92241_IGHV2-70*02_Homosapiens_F_V-REGION_144..433_290nt_1_____290+0=290_partialin3'__>
tag2val[from] = <1>
tag2val[to] = <290>
tag2val[Start] = <176>
tag2val[End] = <184>
tag2val[Strand] = <+>
tag2val[Pattern] = <pattern:AA[CT]NNN[AT]CN>
tag2val[Mismatch] = <.>
tag2val[Sequence] = <aatactaca>
----
```

If all you wanted was to print the input lines as-is it'd be even more trivial but I really think the above is what you're going to want going forward to add various combinations of comparisons and outputs.