# how i can comment (#) 6 lines before and after the matched pattern in sed

Tags: regex, perl, vim, sed

I want to comment(#) 6 lines before and after the matched pattern. 
I referred this question.

[How do I delete a matching line, the line above and the one below it, using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876446/how-do-i-delete-a-matching-line-the-line-above-and-the-one-below-it-using-sed)

I tried to use hold buffer for this solution, but not working.

I have the following sequence occurring multiple times in a file:

```
aaaa  
bbbb  
cccc  
dddd  
eeee  
ffff  
gggg  
hhhh  
iiii  
jjjj  
kkkk  
llll  
mmmm  
nnnn  
oooo
```

If I searched `hhhh`, then the output file should be given below:

```
  aaaa  
  #bbbb  
  #cccc  
  #dddd  
  #eeee  
  #ffff  
  #gggg  
  #hhhh  
  #iiii  
  #jjjj  
  #kkkk  
  #llll  
  #mmmm  
  #nnnn  
  oooo
```

Please help me to do this with sed or any other scripts!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/\n/&/6;tb;$!{N;ba};:b;/SEARCH_STRING/!{P;D};s/\n/&/12;tc;$!{N;bb};:c;s/^/#/gm' file
```

Comment: I have expanded out the one liner and added some explanations

Answer (score 12):

The question is tagged Vim, so… my beloved `:help :global` and `:help :normal` to the rescue!

```
:g/hhhh/-6,+6norm I#
```

`:substitute` variant:

```
:g/hhhh/-6,+6s/^/#
```

Breakdown:

- The `:global` command is used to execute an Ex command for each line matching the given pattern.

  `:g/hhhh/d` would delete every line containing `hhhh`.
- Ex commands usually accept an optional range. A range can use absolute line numbers, `5,15` and/or relative line numbers, `-3,+41`.

  `:g/hhhh/-6,+6d` would delete everything between 6 lines above and 6 lines below every line containing `hhhh`.
- The `:normal` command allows us to execute normal commands from the command-line and it accepts a range, like the other Ex commands. `I#` is the simplest way to insert a `#` at the beginning of a line so we can do `:normal I#` from the command-line, which brings us to the first solution:

  ```
  :g/hhhh/-6,+6norm I#
  ```
- As an Ex command, `:substitute` also accepts a range so we can use it as well to insert a `#` at the beginning of each line in the range, which brings us to the second solution:

  ```
  :g/hhhh/-6,+6s/^/#
  ```

Comment: OK, give me a few moments.

Comment: Oh wow. I love vim. I wish I could upvote you twice. Thank you.

Comment: This can also be done as a “one shot” (instead of `:global`) like this: `/hhhh/;-6,+6 s/^/#` (`norm I#` also works). The pattern sets the cursor position (due to the `;`, see `:help :;`), then the effective range is simply `-6,+6` from that point.

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen, very valuable comment, thanks. That's how I'd do it too, but the OP said his sample block occurred multiple times in a file so I went with a more `:global` approach.

Answer (score 4):

To do this in Perl, you need to read the entire file into an array, then find the index of the matching line and edit the surrounding lines, which can be done with a range.

You must remove undefined values from the array slice, or you will create new entries if your match is near the beginning or end of the file (i.e. less than 6 lines away).

```
perl -we '@a = <>;                      # read whole file
           for (0 .. $#a) {              # loop over indexes
               if ($a[$_] =~ /hhhh/) {   # find match
                   s/^/#/ for grep defined, @a[$_-6 .. $_+6]  # edit
               } 
           }; print @a" hhh.txt
```

In a for loop `$_` is aliased to the elements, which is why we can directly apply a substitution `s///` to it.

This can also possibly be simplified by using [`Tie::File`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aFile).

**Output:**

```
aaaa
#bbbb
#cccc
#dddd
#eeee
#ffff
#gggg
#hhhh
#iiii
#jjjj
#kkkk
#llll
#mmmm
#nnnn
oooo
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are comfortable with sed, I suggest using `grep` to get the context piped to `sed` to create some simple `sed` commands:

**`grep -A6 -B6 -n hhhh file | sed -e 's/[^0-9].*$//' -e 's/$/s|^|#|/' | sed -f- file`**

(The examples below have `-A1` and `-B1` to shorten the length of this output.)

Get line-numbered `-A1` one line after and `-B1` one line before the matching line with `grep -A1 -B1 -n hhhh file` which outputs:

```
7-gggg  
8:hhhh  
9-iiii
```

... which we're going to turn into sed commands to comment out those numbered lines with `| sed -e 's/[^0-9].*$//' -e 's/$/s|^|#|/'`, two sed commands to remove everything after the first non-digit and replace the end of that shortened line with `| sed -e 's|^|#|'`, the replacement which comments out the entire line.  That gets this:

```
7s|^|#|
8s|^|#|
9s|^|#|
```

... and we want to pipe those commands to sed, so we use `-f-` which is equivalent to `-f /dev/stdin` and instructs sed to read commands from stdin.

`grep -A1 -B1 -n hhhh abcd.txt | sed -e 's/[^0-9].*$//' -e 's/$/s|^|#|/' | sed -f- abcd.txt`

```
aaaa  
bbbb  
cccc  
dddd  
eeee  
ffff  
#gggg  
#hhhh  
#iiii  
jjjj  
kkkk  
llll  
mmmm  
nnnn  
oooo
```

Answer (score 0):

** here comes a Perl solution!! **

I would store the whole content in a Array, iterating through the array and flag the iterator variable if the pattern matches. Then remove and add 6 from the iterator variable and there we go, if the flagged variables are given, you can concat the hashtag in front of the line.

to make it more clearly:

```
use File::Slurp;
my $find_counter = 0;
my $line_counter = 0;
my @lines = read_file( 'filename' ) ;
foreach my $line (@lines) { # foreach or for loop
  if ($line =~ /$pattern/) {
    $file_counter = $line_counter;
    last;
  }
  $line_counter++;
}
# loop again through @lines and when the line is between
# $file_counter + - 6 , concat the hashtag in front of the line
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way reads one line at a time which may be better for large files, it avoids reading the whole file into memory.

The array `@prev_lines` hold the number of lines that are to be printed before the match. When a match is found, print the remembered lines with the `#` prefix and set `$num_line_to_print` to the number of lines to print after the match. If the line does not match then see whether lines are to be printed for a previous match. If neither then push the line onto the array in case it matches in the future. If the array now has too many lines, they were not close to the match so just print them. Finally, after the `while` loop just print out any save lines.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $num_lines_wanted = 6;

my @prev_lines;
my $num_line_to_print = 0;

while ( <> ) {
    if ( m/hhhh/ ) {
        while ( scalar(@prev_lines) > 0 ) {
            print "#", shift @prev_lines;
        }
        print "#", $_;
        $num_line_to_print = $num_lines_wanted;
    }
    elsif ( $num_line_to_print > 0 ) {
        print "#", $_;
        $num_line_to_print--;
    }
    else {
        push @prev_lines, $_;
        if ( scalar(@prev_lines) > $num_lines_wanted ) {
            print shift @prev_lines;
        }
    }
}

while ( scalar(@prev_lines) > 0 ) {
    print shift @prev_lines;
}
```

The original question is not clear how to handle input where two `hhhh` lines are within the six lines of each other. The code here restarts the numbering at each match, it prints input lines only once and only adds one `#` even when a line is within the range of two `hhhh` matches.

Comment: @joshy no problems. I just wanted to point out an unspecified aspect of the question and how my answer dealt with it.